# ReFS and block cloning on Windows 10 Enterprise

Tags: windows, ntfs, refs

I am using Windows 10 Enterprise (20H2) and setup a storage space of multiple VHXD containers and a REFS formatted disk. I am interested in the **block cloning** feature, less the explicit dedup command.

Does the explorer support block cloning by duplicating a file manually? I am trying to clone a file several times without any time delay. A similar effect can be seen on Apple File System (*APFS*).

Comment: As far as I understand documentation, ReFS will do this by design, so yes, when you copy a file ReFS will use this feature. Backup software (such as Veeam) uses this feature extensively for Fast Backup and less space utilization.

Comment: Interesting, but I can't confirm this. If I copy/clone a file I still see a copy status bar for the amount of time it would normally take to fully clone a 30 GB file. E.g. on macOS APFS it takes around 500ms to clone 30GB

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. Found this script: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Clone-files-using-ReFS-9644cd1b
I assume and according to your tests explorer doesn't use block cloning. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try and report